# how to get sum of each column new records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about SQL Server. I have a table something like this:

```
productname |Level|  January  | Feburary | March | total
------------x-----x-----------x----------x-------x------
  Rin       | L1  |  10       | 20       |  30   | 60
  Rin       | L2  |  5        | 10       |  10   | 25
  Rin       | L3  |  20       | 5        |  5    | 30
  Pen       | L1  |  5        | 6        |  10   | 21 
  Pen       | L2  |  10       | 10       |  20   | 40
  Pen       | L3  |  30       |10        |  40   | 80
```

based on above table data I want output like below

```
productname |Level|  January  | Feburary | March | total
------------x-----x-----------x----------x-------x------
  Rin       | L1  |   10      | 20       |  30   | 60
  Rin       | L2  |   5       | 10       |  10   | 25
  Rin       | L3  |  20       | 5        |  5    | 30
  RinTotal  |All  |  35       | 35       |  45   | 115
  Pen       | L1  |  5        | 6        |  10   | 21 
  Pen       | L2  |  10       | 10       |  20   | 40
  Pen       | L3  |  30       | 10       |  40   | 80
  PenTotal  | All |  45       | 26       |  70   |141
```

I tried like bellow query

```
SELECT productname
    ,LEVEL
    ,sum(january) AS January
    ,sum(Feburary) AS Feburary )
    ,Sum(march) AS March
    ,Sum(total) AS total
FROM test

UNION

SELECT *
FROM test
```

but its not given exact output .Please point me to right direction on how to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: Please tag the appropriate version of SQL Server.  Spamming multiple tags for a "fishnet effect" will result in a closed question.

Comment: google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
UNION
SELECT PRODUCTNAME+'TOTAL','ALL' AS LEVEL,SUM(JANUARY)AS JANUARY,SUM(FEBURARY)AS FEBURARY),SUM(MARCH)AS MARCH,SUM(TOTAL)AS TOTAL
FROM TEST GROUP BY PRODUCTNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This really belongs in the front end. Group subtotals and such are usually really simple from most reporting tools. Also, don't get lazy and use select *, you should always be explicit in your columns. Since you have a specific order I added a couple of extra columns to use for sorting.

Also don't be afraid to add some white space and formatting to your queries. It makes your life a lot easier to read and later debug.

I think something like this should get you close. Notice I changed to a UNION ALL. When using UNION it will exclude duplicates. Since you know for a fact that there are no duplicate rows a UNION ALL will eliminate the need to check for duplicates.

```
select productname + 'Total' as productname
    , 'All' as level
    , sum(january) as January
    , sum(Feburary) as Feburary
    , Sum(march) as March
    , Sum(total) as total
    , productname as SortName
    , 1 as SortOrder
from test
group by productname

union ALL

select productname
    , level
    , January
    , Feburary
    , March
    , Total
    , productname as SortName
    , 0 as SortOrder
from test 
order by SortName, SortOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `Group by With Rollup`. For more info [***check here***](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT productname=productname + CASE WHEN level IS NULL THEN 'Total' 
                           ELSE '' END, 
               Level=Isnull(level, 'ALL'), 
               Sum(january)  AS January, 
               Sum(feburary) AS Feburary, 
               Sum(march)    AS March, 
               Sum(total)    AS total 
        FROM   Yourtable 
        GROUP  BY rollup ( productname, level )) a 
WHERE  productname IS NOT NULL
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c69d/3)

Comment: HI I execute above query but it is given error:Msg 10707, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
The CUBE() and ROLLUP() grouping constructs are not allowed in the current compatibility mode.  They are only allowed in 100 mode or higher.

Comment: Yes you cannot use `rollup` if compatibility mode is less 100